# Type-safe, generic, empty Collections with static generics

Tags: java, collections

I return empty collections vs. null whenever possible.  I switch between two methods for  doing so using [java.util.Collections](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

```
return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
return Collections.emptyList();
```

where `emptyList()` is supposed to be type-safe.  But I recently discovered:

```
return Collections.<ComplexObject> emptyList();
return Collections.<ComplexObject> singletonList(new ComplexObject());
```

etc.

I see this method in Eclipse Package Explorer:

```
<clinit> () : void
```

but I don't see how this is done in the source code (1.5).  How is this magic tomfoolerie happening!!

**EDIT:
How is the static Generic type accomplished?**

Comment: What is the question? `<clinit>` is not a generic method but the (compiler-generated magic) name of the special constructor method which does class initialization.

Comment: Sorry...should have been more clear.  I think I incorrectly assumed that the static block had something to do with the static generic type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> EDIT: How is the static Generic type
>   accomplished?

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html

```
public class Collections {
    ...
    public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<Object>();
    ...
    public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
        return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can see the link for the implementation of the EmptyList class if you're curious, but for your question, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I knew it was something that simple.  The generic return type prefix is all that allows this?  I learned something today...

Comment: If by "generic return type prefix", you mean the first "<T>", then yes.  I wouldn't call it that though - you shouldn't think of it as part of the return type.  Think of it more as a (method) modifier like "public", "static", and "final". It's the parameterized type modifier on the method declaration that makes a generic method.

Answer (score 22):

```
return Collections.<ComplexObject> emptyList();
```

Using this will get rid of warnings from Eclipse about non-generic collections.

Having said that, a typed empty list is going to be functionally identical to an untyped empty list due to empty list being immutable and Java erasing generic types at compile time.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: "You may want to consider using this just to get rid of any warnings from Eclipse about using non-generic collections." In other words, this is correcting the code, rather than using a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Comment: Unicorns Um, yes. Although the sentiment seems to be that warnings don't matter and do something random to get rid of them.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: I've reworded it now.  However, it doesn't change that an **immutable** empty list that is typed is going to be identical to one that is untyped.  In my opinion, the warnings about using non-generic collections are pointless anyway; if someone wants to use a non-generic collection, why should the compiler flag that as a warning?

Comment: Unicorns: Raw types are provided for backward compatibility. To use them is not idiomatic Java.

Answer (score 2):

`<clinit>` is the static initializer block. It is a block of code which is executed exactly once (when the class is loaded).

So, instead of writing

```
class  A  {
   static int x = 5;
}
```

One can write:

```
class A {
   static int x;

   static {  // static initializer starts
      x = 5; 
   }
}
```

These two classes are equivalent. Inside a static initializer block one can place arbitrary code and thus initialize static fields with the results of complicated calculations.

Answer (score 1):

`<clinit>` is the name of the method into which the class initialization code is collected by during compilation. (That is, all of the code inside `static {}` blocks, and the initializers of static members, in source code order.)

It has nothing to do with explicit type parameters in method invocations.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a similar solution, but for more current time (2023/Apr) where one has moved on to using `List.of()` as a terse replacement for `Collections.emptyList()`...

In the same way the type is prefixed to the method in

`Collections.<ComplexObject>emptyList();`

Use the same method-prefix pattern:

`List.<ComplexObject>of();`