# How do I set an empty list of a certain type

Tags: java

We have `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` but it is not typed, which shows an eclipse warning. How do I set an empty list of a certain type.

Comment: It is always a good practice to put you code or example in here.

Comment: Is your List using generics List<E>?

Comment: I just answered this on a question that appears to be close to a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113895/501113

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this

```
Collections.<String> emptyList();
```

See this also [Type-safe, generic, empty Collections with static generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625579/type-safe-generic-empty-collections-with-static-generics)

Answer (score 15):

To get an empty `List` of `String` for example:

```
List<String> list = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

Answer (score 8):

**Since Java 10: use *var* keyword and *List.of()***

*Disclaimer*: this will give you a `List<Object>`. If you want a **typed** List, you should not use the keyword `var` for an empty list. But note that `var list = List.of("hello", "world");` will give you a **typed** list, but not empty.

In Java 10, var keyword was introduced to allow local variable type inference. In other words the type for the local variable will be inferred by the compiler, so the developer does not need to declare it.

Hence, you can use the following statement to create an empty list:

```
var list = List.of()  // since Java 10, use the var keyword, List.of() was introduced in Java 9.
```

**Since Java 9: use *List.of()***

Since Java 9, there is the convenient [List.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) static factory methods, that provide a convenient way to create immutable lists. 
Example:

```
List<String> list = list.of();
```

The List instances created by these methods have the following characteristics:

- structurally immutable: elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced. Otherwise the `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown.
- disallow null elements. Otherwise `NullPointerException` is thrown.
- serializable if all elements are serializable.
- ... see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

**Prior to Java 9: use *Collections. emptyList()***

> The convenient method emptyList() returns an empty list (immutable).
>   This list is serializable. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--)

```
List<String> list = Collections.<String> emptyList(); // prior Java 9
```

Note that `Collections.<String> emptyList()` returns the constant : `EMPTY_LIST`

Comment: Nice! The advantage is that the generic type information is not needed to be written twice. Note further that the returned empty list instance is still a constant, so you do not create unneeded instances. Thus, you could say it does not return "an" empty immutable list, but "the" empty immutable list instance, in my case (Java 13) `ImmutableCollections.ListN.EMPTY_LIST`.

Answer (score 7):

To call `List.of()` while specifying a type, use `List.<Class>of()`, for example:

```java
List.<String>of()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Collections.emptyList();
You can check the jdk document for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use one of these:

1. `new ArrayList<String>()`
2. `Arrays.asList("item of the specific type")`

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
Collections.<Type>emptyList();
```

where `Type` is the type you want to type cast the list to.